# Creating InetAddress object in Java

Tags: java, ip

I am trying to convert an address specified by an IP number or a name, both in String (i.e. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`), into an *InetAdress* object. There's no constructor but rather static methods that return an *InetAddress*. So if I get a host name it's not a problem, but what if I get the IP number? There's one method that gets *byte[]* but I'm not sure how that can help me. All other methods gets the host name.

[InetAddress API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You should be able to use *getByName* or *getByAddress*.

> The host name can either be a machine
>   name, such as "java.sun.com", or a
>   textual representation of its IP
>   address

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
```

The method that takes a byte array can be used like this:

```
byte[] ipAddr = new byte[]{127, 0, 0, 1};
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
```

Comment: What do you do, when you got numbers bigger then 127? For example IP 192.168.0.1. Do you mask int with 0xFF? Or you just cast int to byte?

Comment: @MatejKormuth I think masking with 0xFF should work.

Comment: @matej-kormuth you can also express it like Inet4AddressImpl does: `byte[] loopback = {0x7f,0x00,0x00,0x01};`

Comment: "Default constructor cannot handle exception type UnknownHostException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

Comment: Helps to enclose InetAddress creation in a try/catch statement.

Answer (score 9):

From the API for InetAddress

> The host name can either be a machine
>   name, such as "java.sun.com", or a
>   textual representation of its IP
>   address. If a literal IP address is
>   supplied, only the validity of the
>   address format is checked.

Answer (score 7):

```
ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {
        (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)0, (byte)102}
);
```

Answer (score 3):

InetAddress.getByName also works for ip address.

From the JavaDoc

> The host name can either be a machine
>   name, such as "java.sun.com", or a
>   textual representation of its IP
>   address. If a literal IP address is
>   supplied, only the validity of the
>   address format is checked.

Answer (score 3):

The api is fairly easy to use.

```
// Lookup the dns, if the ip exists.
 if (!ip.isEmpty()) {
     InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
     dns = inetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

InetAddress class can be used to store IP addresses in IPv4 as well as IPv6 formats. You can store the IP address to the object using either `InetAddress.getByName()` or `InetAddress.getByAddress()` methods.

In the following code snippet, I am using `InetAddress.getByName()` method to store IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

```
InetAddress IPv4 = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
InetAddress IPv6 = InetAddress.getByName("2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:1.2.3.4");
```

You can also use `InetAddress.getByAddress()` to create object by providing the byte array.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{127, 0, 0, 1});
```

Furthermore, you can use `InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress()` to get the local address and `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` to get the address registered with the machine name.

```
InetAddress loopback = InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(); // output: localhost/127.0.0.1
InetAddress local = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); // output: <machine-name>/<ip address on network>
```

Note- make sure to surround your code by try/catch because `InetAddress` methods return  `java.net.UnknownHostException`

Answer (score 0):

This is a project for getting IP address of any website , it's usefull and so easy to make.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnkownHostExceptiin;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        try{
            InetAddress addr = InetAddresd.getByName("www.yahoo.com");
            System.out.println(addr.getHostAddress());

          }catch(UnknownHostException e){
             e.printStrackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```