# I have a "could not connect to host" Logcat message while trying to connect to FTP server, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, mobile, ftp-client

I'm developing an application on Android that connects to a FTP server to upload and download files. To make the connection I'm using the apache commons-net library's FTPClient class based on [this](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=28) and I'm working on Eclipse.

But I get the following message on my Logcat:

```
07-04 21:11:44.196: D/USB Virtual(14708): Error: could not connect to host ftp://xxx.xxx
```

The following is my manifest permissions:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I'm really lost as to why I can't connect to my FTP server, in the console there're no errors showing. Am I missing something? I would thank any help.

I'm adding the code I'm using to connect to my FTP server:

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password,
        int port) {
    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
                    //host is ftp://looner-project.zxq.net
        mFTPClient.connect(host);
        mFTPClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(host));


        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {

            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            return status;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is your device connected to the internet?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet

Comment: my device is connected to internet, the problem is that whenever my app tries to connect to the FTP server I get the message `Error: could not connect to host ftp://xxx.xxx`

Comment: try after removing "ftp://" : 

mFTPClient.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", port_num);

Answer (score 0):

Things to check...

**1.** Check your internet connection.

**2.** Are you giving the Url to the ftp site correct ??

**3.** If its password protected, are you giving them correctly ??

**4.** Using command prompt check it. Give the below command to check it.

```
ftp www.your_ftp_site.com
```

**after the above command you will be prompted for username and password.**

I am also attaching my code which i used to upload audio file to the server to make it clear...

```
    import java.io.File;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;

    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

    import android.util.Log;



    public class MyOwn {

        public void goforIt(){


            FTPClient con = null;

            try
            {
                con = new FTPClient();
                con.connect("www.mysamle.net");                 // Its dummy Address

                if (con.login("uju495", "Stevejobs!!"))
                {
                    con.enterLocalPassiveMode();                   // Very Important

                    con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);        //  Very Important
                    String data = "/sdcard/Vivekm4a.m4a";

                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                    boolean result = con.storeFile("/Ads/Vivekm4a.m4a", in);
                    in.close();
                    if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                    con.logout();
                    con.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

    }
```

Comment: my code is almost like yours but the connection isn't happening, I'm really lost here.

Comment: @Uriel: connect method has several overloads; maybe try with InetAddress parameter. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719449/creating-inetaddress-object-in-java/5719553#5719553)