# FTP Client in Java Android Eclipse

Tags: android, ftp-client

First of all - This is my first question I ask on StackOverflow. And I'm from Germany, my english is not so good :)

I try to create a FTP Client as a Android App. I'm coding with Eclipse and the Android SDK.

This is my Code, but it doesn't work.
I use the Apache Commons FTP Library.
Can you help me? I don't want a functional Code, but I love to get Advice to get the Code working.
Thanks!

So here is my code:

---

```
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

    public class speechatStart extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_load);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            FTPClient client = new FTPClient(); 

            TextView ausgabe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ausgabe);


            try {
            client.connect("ftp-web.ohost.de");
            client.login("ftp1857836", "123456789"); 
                String filename = "file1.txt"; 
                FileInputStream fis = null; 
                    fis = new FileInputStream(filename); 
                    client.storeFile(filename, fis); 
                    client.logout(); 
                    fis.close();

                    ausgabe.setText(fis);

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ausgabe.setText("SocketException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ausgabe.setText("IOException");
        } 

        }
    });
```

---

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: @speechat try to print all exception stack trace and show your logcat: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

Comment: Please hide your ftp server / login for your own safety =)

Comment: @Ion Aalbers - Thanks, but this is an empty server i just use for tests. I've enough other free webspaces...

Comment: @BlaineOmega - It could not even connect. It just does nothing...

Comment: maybe it should set file type to binary

see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925572/ftpclient-java-upload-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Apache-Commons FTp library didn't gave reliable solution for me.So that I have used [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/) which give me better solution and API is also much simple.

```
 Example:

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.connect("ftp.host.com");
    if(client.isConnected())
    {
        client.login("username","password");
        if(client.isAuthenticated())
         {
              client.upload(new java.io.File("localFile.txt"));
          }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337165/i-have-a-could-not-connect-to-host-logcat-message-while-trying-to-connect-to-f?rq=1) Ich habe in diesem tollen Forum eine Lösung gefunden, die funktioniert! Vielen Dank an alle!

Comment: Somit ist diese Frage beantwortet und geschlossen.

Comment: Check this: [link...........](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337165/i-have-a-could-not-connect-to-host-logcat-message-while-trying-to-connect-to-f?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download file try next code:

```
ftpClient.retrieveFile(filename, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

To upload change to

```
ftpClient.storeFile(filename, inputStream);
```

It seems that you are doing logout before stream is closed.

Comment: By the way, have you added    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to your manifest file?