# How do I create loop using InetAddress?

Tags: java

I want to create a loop for pinging the PCs in the LAN using the IP address of the base mechanin which is of type Inetaddress. I am trying to convert it in integer form but an error is occurring.

This is my code; the error is on line number 17 and the error is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at practice.trying.main(trying.java:27)`

```
 /**************************/
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.*;
    public class trying {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        String s ;
        int[] ia=new int[4] ;
        System.out.println("enter the ip ");
        s=in.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        String st1[]=s.split(".");
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
         ia[i]=Integer.parseInt(st1[i]);
     System.out.println(ia[i]);
        }
    }
    }
    /*********************************/
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is readable.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)` arrays are base 0. Also `split()` expects a regex.

Comment: For future reference, `(trying.java:27)` refers to the class (`trying.java`) and line number (`27`) in which your error is occurring, so when debugging, start there.  And if you already knew this... please point out to SO which line it is exactly.

Comment: There's nothing about an `InetAddress` here. If you're trying to create an `InetAddress` object, then [just create it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5719449/1068283) and don't bother with all this `split` junk.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter what you type into your standard output, this

```
String st1[]=s.split(".");
```

will result in an array of size 0. So

```
Integer.parseInt(st1[i]);
```

with any value of `i` will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The reason for this is that `String#split(String)` expects a regular expression pattern. In addition it doesn't include any empty strings.

`.` is a special character in regular expressions meaning any character. So you are trying to split around any character and discarding empty strings. So you end up with no elements.

You want to use

```
String st1[]=s.split("\\.");
```

so that the `.` special character is escaped in the regular expression.

---

Note also that your for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
```

will also give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i` reaches `4`. Remember that array indices start at 0. You need

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

or better yet

```
for(int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
```

---

You're using one loop but 2 arrays.