# Can't ping for check server condition

Tags: android, http, ping

I have a Django webserver runing on `192.168.1.100:8000`.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
public boolean isServerReachable()
{
    try {
        InetAddress.getByName("http://192.168.1.100:8000/").isReachable(500);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("result",e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the error that I receive:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://192.168.1.100:8000/": No address associated with hostname
```

But as you can see, here is my server running:

[image]

What I'm missing? I just try to check if the server is online or not.

Comment: Does leaving off the "http://" part affect things or not? 

In the example on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719449/creating-inetaddress-object-in-java#5719553), they didn't use it.

Comment: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "192.168.1.100:8000/interface": No address associated with hostname

Comment: Did you leave off the last slash as well? Could you try the getbyAddress function mentioned on that other page?

Comment: Can you provide me an example? I don't know how to put there the port.